# Discord.py - bot deletes message after it sends

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I've recently been trying to make it so that when someone types a specific command the bot deletes their message. Everything I tried before didn't work so I have absolutely no idea how to do this. I'm new to discord.py so my knowledge is quite limited.

```
#making sure the command only works in the specific channel
async def is_channel(ctx):
    return ctx.channel.id == 873501773971726346

#the actual code
@client.command(case_sensitive=True)
@commands.check(is_channel)
async def resus(ctx,*, saymsg=None):
    if saymsg==None:
        return await ctx.send("To reserve a username type - !resus (your discord tag) (the username you want) (if you want verification) You can also add some extra information if you would like. Any spam/troll reservations will result in a warning and or mute.")
        


    sayEmbed = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name} Said", color = discord.Color.blue(), description=f"{saymsg}")
    sayEmbed.timestamp = ctx.message.created_at
    channelf = client.get_channel(873564203535958047)
    await channelf.send(embed = sayEmbed)
```

Comment: Just use `await ctx.message.delete()`?

Comment: @Dominik Thanks, but were do I put it so it deletes the users message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right above the if statement you want to put await ctx.message.delete() which will delete their message and then run the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i usually do but when waiting for input but you can use it on a normal message

```
  title = "Something...",
  description = "||This request will timeout in 60s||"
  )
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  try:
    amount_of_codes = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel, timeout=60.0)
  except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await ctx.channel.send("Request timed out")
```